# I'm trying to make a dynamic CSS (using php header) but I have problems in client

Tags: php, xampp, dynamic-css

I renamed my stylesheet as `full.css.php` and on the very beginning of the file i wrote this code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   //here I want to set all my css variables
   $font_color = '#ccf';

?>
//here starts the css
body{
    color: <?php echo $font_color?>;
}
```

The browser is giving me this: `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://localhost/root/_Viewer/css/full.css.php".`.

And then error: *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"* (this is the first brace from body css declaration).

If I look in source, I find that my file was sent as `application/javascript` file, not as `text/css`:

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='_Viewer/css/full.css.php'></script>
```

I know dynamic CSS won't be cached, but it's fine with me. It's more important now to have some settings easy to access.
Need help to fix this.

Btw: I'm running this under **XAMPP** !

-i forgot to mention: i'm doing similar with one of my js files and it's working just fine ( `header("Content-type: application/javascript");` )

Comment: no need to use header just remove that line of header

Comment: Did you try to load it as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="_Viewer/css/full.css.php" type="text/css">` instead of `script`?

Comment: then, how I will use PHP code inside my CSS file (to set variables) and also, the rendered content to be interpreted as css by the browser? - my alternative would be to force Apache to parse a .css file as php

Comment: The answer i gave you in my previous comment works - checked myself. I'm not posting it as answer though, because i just found similar question, so i'll just give you the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445424/include-css-with-php-file-extension

Comment: @derei because it is a php file not a css file. The php sends headers of css. A JS file is no different than a CSS file they are both just text files that get sent to the client side to be handled on the client side. Whey would linking to the php file as a script be any different than linking to a php file by a style sheet?

Comment: Yeah, thanks ! I've checked too :D .The problem was that I had a function that automatically detected file extension and loaded it appropriately (all files were retrieved from an array). And so, my `full.css.php` was loaded as `php`. Of course, I forgot about it and I was blaming Apache for this.