# DB encoded images being displayed using Photoswipe

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

I want to build a gallery using [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/).

The images are stored in the database with json encoded format:

```
[{"name":"files/130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar_e12bad6z.jpg","usrName":"130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar.jpg","size":62595,"type":"image/jpeg","searchStr":"130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar.jpg,!20100826_marias_560x372.jpg,!125255351_5169310e93.jpg,!:sStrEnd"},{"name":"files/20100826_marias_560x372_nbajgoth.jpg","usrName":"20100826_marias_560x372.jpg","size":44958,"type":"image/jpeg"},{"name":"files/125255351_5169310e93_f0udoyh3.jpg","usrName":"125255351_5169310e93.jpg","size":131453,"type":"image/jpeg"}][{"name":"files/130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar_e12bad6z.jpg","usrName":"130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar.jpg","size":62595,"type":"image/jpeg","searchStr":"130813-263472-LA-Dive-Bar-HMS-Bounty-Bar.jpg,!20100826_marias_560x372.jpg,!125255351_5169310e93.jpg,!:sStrEnd"},{"name":"files/20100826_marias_560x372_nbajgoth.jpg","usrName":"20100826_marias_560x372.jpg","size":44958,"type":"image/jpeg"},{"name":"files/125255351_5169310e93_f0udoyh3.jpg","usrName":"125255351_5169310e93.jpg","size":131453,"type":"image/jpeg"}]
```

**What's happening:** the images are not showing up.

**The problem:** the following code:

1. `style="background-image: url('.$myImage1.');"`
2. `href="'.$myImage1.'"`
3. `src="'.$myImage1.'"`

Is retrieving the following (see the code and the neon green numbers):

[image: ![enter image description here]

> background-image: url();
>
> href
>
> src(unknown)

**What's wrong here?** Before, I managed to make images display, in another page, by using the following: `src="'.$myImage = $myArray[0]['name'].'"`. And it worked (wasn't using Photoswipe).

For Photoswype, I'm having all the requirements mentioned [here](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html).
It seems to work, the image space is created and if I click there, appears the following:

[image]

I checked also the following links:

[How do i run PHP inside CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367134/how-do-i-run-php-inside-css)

[How to use PHP inside css file [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338116/how-to-use-php-inside-css-file)

and tested to do the way they say: `<? echo $myImage1; ?>`

*That didn't work.*

**Note:** in case seeing the code in a context would help:

`print_r($myArray1);` doesn't retrieve values

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $category=$row['Company_Category'];
        $name=$row['Company_Name'];
        $subcategory=$row['Company_Subcategory'];
        $image1 = $row['Image'];
        $myArray1 = json_decode($image1, true);
        print_r($myArray1);
        $myImage1 =$myArray1[0]['name'];
    echo '<figure class="gallery-image-item" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" style="background-image: url('.$myImage1.')">
              <a href="'.$myImage1.'" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="960x640">
                 <img class="gallery-thumb" src="'.$myImage1.'" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
               </a>
               <figcaption class="hidden caption" itemprop="caption description">'.$row['Description'].'</figcaption>
            </figure>';}
```

**Working case:**

`print_r($myArray);` retrieves values

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $image = $row['Company_Logo'];
        $myArray = json_decode($image, true);
        echo '<img src="'.$myImage = $myArray[0]['name'].'" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>';
```

**My question:** How do I make this work?

Comment: Sure json data is acessible? Try `print_r($myArray1)`.

Comment: Nothing shows up.

Is it because I have: inside of a while the `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: because that's the only difference from the case mentioned in the message that worked