# Have to run a counter using PHP in a css file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website wherein I have two icons in the header and these two icons have badges on them. And I've implemented these badges using pseudocodes(after/before). Now the problem I'm facing is, I've to run a counter and for that I have to use php in the css file. Basically I need to calculate the "content" (100 is a dummy value).

I am adding the code below to help you understand the issue.

could it be done?
How could it be done?
and what would be the  extension of the file?

TIA

```
.badgeq:after {
        content: "100";
        position: relative;
        background: rgba(0,0,255,1);
        height: 2rem;
        top: 0rem;
        right: 0.5rem;
        width: 2rem;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        line-height: 2rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .badgeq {
        display: flex;
        min-width: 10px;
        padding: 3px 7px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 1;
        color: #35BBE6;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    a.badgeq:focus, a.badgeq:hover {
        color: #27408b;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    <?php

    include('dbConnect.php');

     
        if(!isset($_SESSION['zuser_id5'] ) || empty($_SESSION['zuser_id5']))
        {
            if(!isset($_SESSION['zuser_id9'] ) || empty($_SESSION['zuser_id9']))
            {header("Location: /"); }
        }


        ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Vaibhav Chouhan Abhishek Kashyap Srishti Mahatma"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Zigzobs|Revolutionizing Recruitment">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/zigsaw.png">
        <title>Zigzobs|Revolutionizing Recruitment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-justified">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="user.php"><img src="images/zigsaw.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                
                    
                <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center navbar-header">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a href="notificationpage.php"  class="badge badgeq"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="msg1.php" class="badge badgeq"><i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="user.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="alljobs.php">Selling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="employerhome.php">Buying</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="applicationstatus.html">Status</a></li> -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add Credits</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="https://rzp.io/i/RXDp" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>500</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="https://rzp.io/i/fTRj" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>1000</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="https://rzp.io/i/Q4Ex" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>2000</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="https://rzp.io/i/3TKh" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>5000</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="https://rzp.io/i/kQmh" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>10000</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" action="searchjob.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Jobs" name="keyword_job">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submito">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6a575d0f1f.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP in a CSS file [can be done, awkwardly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338116/how-to-use-php-inside-css-file) - but why not just to throw a `<span>` into `.badgeq` and write the number there in the template, instead of using `:after`?