# how can i get an image from database through id with css?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have this database table:

```
ID Nome Country Imagem
1  John USA     images/######.jpg
2  Ana  USA     images/######.jpg
3  ##   ##      images/######.jp
```

How can I start my code? I Want to get the image through the ID and put it in the background.

```
.background {
   backgound-image: url(...);
}
```

Is This Possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?
Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you give more details about what you want to achieve

Comment: You're going to have to use a scripting language.  This is not possible through just CSS

Comment: can you give an example??

Comment: it is not possible using css

Comment: ok that is what i whant to know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible when you link php file as css.

And return appropriate header

Like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906870/1011278

2) Second variant is to do something like this:

```
.background {
   backgound-image: url(/user-image.php?id=1);
}
```

If i got right.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your css code in your header.php or footer.php like,

```
<?php
$imgUrl = 'images/######.jpg';  //get corresponding filename and path from db
?>
<style>
.background {
   backgound-image: url(<?php echo $imgUrl ?>);
}
</style>
<?php
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you know MySQL?

Anyway, after the connection to the DB, do this:

```
$bg = $mysqli->query("SELECT Imagem FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ID=2")->fetch_object()->Imagem;
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend the usage of `mysql_` functions. Also seems to broad to be answered at this time. HTML and CSS will be needed..

Comment: You canno't directly connect CSS to PHP, so you need to put the css code in your HTML page and in "background: url()", put 

`<?php echo $bg; ?>`