# Setting dynamic value of background image in css file in php codeigniter framework

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework in php and I want set dynamic value from database to background image property in css, so I set the css file with .php extention and set header type

to but when I put any php code in css file it stops working, so please can anybody will help me??

Comment: The php code in css file? Please you share your code for more under standing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445424/include-css-with-php-file-extension Please follow this answer.

Comment: <?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8 ");?>
<?php $url=echo base_url();
 $img1=$slidersInfo[0]['sliderImage'];
 $img2=$slidersInfo[1]['sliderImage'];
 $img3=echo $slidersInfo[2]['sliderImage']; ?>                                                                                                               .bg-img-1 { background-image: url(../Admin/images/<?php echo $img1; ?>);
}
.bg-img-2 { background-image: url(../Admin/images/<?php echo $img2; ?>);
}
.bg-img-3 {
 background-image: url(../Admin/images/<?php echo $img3; ?>);
}

Comment: my css file is as above ...